# My graphics card doesn't show up in the monitor settings window or DirectX diagnostic tool. Is my computer using it?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics

I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit with a touchscreen laptop.

I feel almost silly asking "Is my computer using my graphics card?" since I nearly know for a fact it is... but I have to ask.

I was using [PCMag's](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2406120,00.asp) tutorial for finding out which graphics card you have, which involves right clicking the desktop, and selecting screen resolution, then advanced settings. When I do this, my (as I understand it) default integrated graphics show up: "Intel HD Graphics 4400"

I knew I have a GeForce graphics card... it's on a sticker on my laptop for goodness' sake... so I followed [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Out-What-Graphics-Card-You-Have) to the Device Manager and saw the Intel 4400 listed, followed by the NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M.

So... if it's not showing up in my screen resolution window as PCMag said it should... is my computer using it as the "main graphics card" of sorts (my understanding of graphics processing is fairly limited).

Edit: I googled "find directx version" because I wanted to know that as well... which led me to the directx diagnostic tool (dxdiag)... which also lists the Intel 4400 as my graphics adapter. This is slightly concerning me now.

Comment: The Intel Adapter also shows up in the DirectX Diagnostic Tool, not the GeForce. (I'll add this to the main question)

Comment: Its probably using switchable graphics. It probably should switch over on load or games I guess?

Comment: You have both - perhaps via Optimus, which means it will switch to the higher power card when needed.  As this is transparent, running dxdiag is probably not enough to trigger it, while running a game would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes your computer is using it. but not on windows desktop. your pc uses nvidia gpu when you start games. you can tell your pc to use nvidia for any program or specifies programs using nvidia control panel [image]